# Should I write more SQL to be more efficient, or less SQL to be less buggy?

Tags: sql

I've been writing a lot of one-off SQL queries to return exactly what a certain page needs and no more.

I could reuse existing queries and issue a number of SQL requests linear to the number of records on the page.  As an example, I have a query to return People and a query to return Job Details for a person.  To return a list of people with their job details I could query once for people and then once for each person to retrieve their job details.  I've found that in most cases that solution returns things in a reasonable amount of time, but I don't know how well it will scale in my environment.  Instead I've been writing queries to join people + job details, or people + salary history, etc.

I'm looking at my models and I see how I could shave off maybe 30% of my code if I were to re-use existing queries.  This is a big temptation.  Is it a bad thing to go for reuse over efficiency in general or does it all come down to the specific situation?  Should I first do it the easy way and then optimize later, or is it best to get the code knocked out while everything is fresh in my mind?  Thoughts, experiences?

Comment: what is the programming environment using the queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Architectural decisions such as this one always depend on the exact circumstances. But as a general rule, loops over one dataset in order to retreive additional data should always be avoided. A join normally has a lot better performance - especially if there is network latency between the web server and the DB server.

If you still want to have separate queries, you should at least construct the fetch of the second entity through a `WHERE IN (...)` construct so that you fetch all lines at once.

Code duplication is alwasy bad and SQL queries tend to be very similar, yet not exactly the same. I think that using an ORM tool, even such a basic as Linq-to-SQL helps a lot in reducing the overhead of specialized queries.

Answer (score 1):

If they are available for your programming environment I would consider looking into using O/RM solutions, then you don't have to write much SQL at all, if any.

Comment: You're answering a "how to use SQL" question with "don't"?  Really?

Comment: @quillbreaker the question was "should I write more sql or less", I am going with the extreme less, none.

Answer (score 1):

Both.  Every decision you make is going to be selecting an appropriate path depending upon requirements.

For example, in most systems, typically you will have two classes of views - views which provide base layers (some joins within a subsystem, minimal work, no aggregations, minimal data masking (no ISNULL(datecol, '1/1/1900')) and views which provide full encapsulation (aggregation, joins of data from different subsystems, conforming of data).

In these cases, you are likely to have heavy re-use (but more frequent changes) of the base layer and thus good testing and assurance that they are reliable and lighter re-use (but less frequent changes) of higher-level abstractions and correspondingly less testing and assurance.

Base views will be coded for most efficiency since usage patterns are not as predictable, higher level views will have fewer use cases, and so efficiency will probably only be needed in certain types of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Write new queries for efficiency, and compare the results against the tried and true queries for testing, in order to maintain quality.

If the deadline is short, you'd pick quality over efficiency and use the tried and true ones, since they'll save you from development time and testing.